# How do I adjust the margin for Flutter AppBar?

Tags: flutter

How do I customize the app bar such that the back button is not so close to the border? I want to achieve this for all pages.

I can't seem to set margins for the app bar.

[Reference to the back button close to border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn67w.png)

Here are my codes

```
// General Theme

AppBarTheme(
    centerTitle: true,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      headline6: TextStyle(
        color: kTextColor,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

```
// Individual Screen


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'components/body.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hello'),
      ),
      body: Body(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome @Dude, exactly what I am looking for, the only thing is that I cant define it for all appBar in a single code like in ThemeData

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create your own custom widget for this, your custom widget can be a `Row` widget with multiples child.

Also, checkout `SafeArea` widget.

```dart
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: MyCustomWidget(title: 'Hello'),
      ),
      body: Body(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this will complicate stuff as I don't want to have to code up the back button to tie to the routes, are there any workaround to just putting margins on the leading icon in general?

Comment: But the button back is just a pop is something very simple.

Comment: @WeiChun You don't have to code all the routes back. There is a widget called `BackButton` and it's EXACTLY what is displayed on your first screen, and it ll calculate the route automatically.